# Reading from a USB Device in Go using karalabe package

Tags: go, usb

I am using karalabe USB package (since it does not depend on libusb installation on Win 10) and I can successfully find a micro:bit, but no output is read into the buffer, i.e. count is always 0:

```
func show_read(device usb.Device) {
    var buffer []byte
    for {
        count, err := device.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading:", err)
        } else if count != 0 {
            fmt.Print(string(buffer))
        }
    }
}

func ShowDevices() {
    hids, err := usb.Enumerate(0x0D28, 0x0204)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i, hid := range hids {
        fmt.Printf("HID #%d\n", i)
        fmt.Printf("  OS Path:      %s\n", hid.Path)
        fmt.Printf("  Vendor ID:    %#04x\n", hid.VendorID)
        fmt.Printf("  Product ID:   %#04x\n", hid.ProductID)
        var device, err = hid.Open()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error opening", err)
        } else {
            go show_read(device)
        }
    }
}
```

e.g. this outputs:

```
HID #0
  OS Path:      \\?\hid#vid_0d28&pid_0204&mi_03#8&30686a44&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}
  Vendor ID:    0x0d28
  Product ID:   0x0204
```

I have an existing program on the micro:bit that does connect and output successfully to a python version (which I am porting to Go) - and this works and shows that output is being sent from the micro:bit.

Note: If I open the micro:bit REPL through the Mu Editor, the Python code fails to open/connect (which is technically correct) but the Go program still runs without throwing an error, which implies that the device isn't actually being opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much of this was necessary, but I solved this by:

1. Using go.bug.st/serial - see also https://godoc.org/go.bug.st/serial
2. and adding `uart.init(115200,8,None,1)` to my micro:bit python code

It's possible that karalabe would also work now that the uart is initialized correctly...

Here is some working serial code - which fine for my purposes (only tested on windows) - though there is obviously some tidying to do - the program exits when the micro:bit is disconnected.

```
package usb

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "go.bug.st/serial"
    "go.bug.st/serial/enumerator"
)

const VID = "0D28"
const PID = "0204"

func show_read(device serial.Port) {
    buffer := make([]byte, 100)
    for {
        count, err := device.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error reading:", err)
        } else if count != 0 {
            fmt.Print(string(buffer[:count]))
        }
    }
}

func ShowDevices() {
    ports, err := enumerator.GetDetailedPortsList()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, port := range ports {
        if port.IsUSB && (port.VID == VID) && (port.PID == PID) {
            UBIT_MODE := &serial.Mode{
                BaudRate: 115200,
                DataBits: 8,
                Parity:   serial.NoParity,
                StopBits: serial.OneStopBit,
            }
            fmt.Printf("Found port: %s\n", port.Name)
            fmt.Printf("   USB ID     %s:%s\n", port.VID, port.PID)
            fmt.Printf("   USB serial %s\n", port.SerialNumber)
            device, err := serial.Open(port.Name, UBIT_MODE)
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
            go show_read(device)
        }
    }
}
```